# Amazon S3 - Images sometimes 404

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon S3 for images and randomly images 404 when loading from Amazon S3?

Why? How can I fix this bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could enable access-logging and try to identify the failed requests in the logfiles.
You can enable access-log for a bucket in the AWS-Console. Select your bucket in the left column, then 'Actions' -> 'Properties' -> 'Logging'

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is no bug.

S3 has been designed to only come close to a 0% error rate. Some requests will always fail.

Because of this you will need to implement a method on your side to try multiple times to load an image before you give up.